# An appropriate way of adding a feature to a time series forecasting model input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, pytorch

I have been working on a demand forecasting model for a while. I am using an LSTM model to predict the  future demand of a product family of a company. To solidify and exemplify my raw data, an example is as below;

---

## Unprocessed data

```
np.random.seed(1)

raw_data = pd.DataFrame({"product_type": ["A"]*3 + ["B"]*3 + ["C"]*3, "product_family": ["x", "y", "z", "t", "u", "y", "p", "k", "l"]})

for col in [str(x)+"-"+str(y) for x in range(2015, 2020) for y in range(1, 13)]:
    raw_data[col] = np.random.randint(10, 50, 9)

raw_data.head()

  product_type product_family  2015-1  ...  2019-10  2019-11  2019-12
0            A              x      47  ...       15       39       38
1            A              y      22  ...       37       28       29
2            A              z      18  ...       41       41       37
3            B              t      19  ...       32       44       29
4            B              u      21  ...       22       29       25
[5 rows x 62 columns]
```

As can be seen above, the data has two nominal feature, and the rest are the past demand data.

---

First, let me interpret what I do in my case:

---

I first select the `product_family` to be predicted and let that `product_family` be `"x"`:

```
prod_family_data = raw_data.loc[raw_data.product_family == "x", raw_data.columns[2:]].to_numpy()
```

Then I create the x and y of the training set:

```
x_train, y_train = [], []

for i in range(0, len(prod_family_data) - 12):
    x_train.append(prod_family_data[i: i + 12])
    y_train.append(prod_family_data[i + 12])

x_train = np.array(x_train)

y_train = np.array(y_train)

array([[47, 11, 21, 32, 34, 14, 35, 49, 44, 42, 31, 18],
       .  
       .
       .
       [14, 20, 45, 13, 48, 43, 45, 49, 49, 37, 15, 39]], dtype=object)

y_train

array([28, 38, 12, 12, 23, 29, 19, 23, 39, 38, 18, 40, 46, 48, 44, 27, 10,
       24, 25, 22, 15, 28, 44, 46, 22, 12, 45, 47, 38, 21, 46, 26, 12, 21,
       18, 14, 20, 45, 13, 48, 43, 45, 49, 49, 37, 15, 39, 38])

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1)

x_train.shape

(48, 12, 1)

y_train.shape

(48,)
```

Then I predict the `product_family`'s demand with a LSTM model, then I go back to the start, select another `product_family`, rinse and repeat.

What I wonder is if there is a way to add the `product_family` feature to the input (and may be product_type and other nominal qualities of products in the future too) of the model, and feed it to the model all at once?

Also, is there a way to bound the demand data with the timestamps to the input so that the model will catch the trend or seasonality of the data/

Comment: You must detrend the data, excluding such effect as inflation e.g., otherwise your model will always undershoot or overshoot. As far as seasonality is concerned, you may add averages for the last week, month, quarter, year, 2 years and see what is most helpful for your data.

Answer (score 1):

I would first recommend you to re-think the shape of your dataset. A classic time serie dataset "X" feeded to a LSTM network will have a 3D shape as :

1. `X.shape[0]` : number of time series (to use for training / testing)
2. `X.shape[1]` : number of timesteps in the time series
3. `X.shape[2]` : number of features of each time series

In your example, assuming you have only one time serie per unique pair (product_type, product_familly), grouping your time series by product family "x" should translate into :

1. `X.shape[0]` : number of product_type including "x" product_familly
2. `X.shape[1]` : number of timesteps in the "x" product_familly sell amount
3. `X.shape[2]` : 1, because your only feature seems to be sell amount

You could add the product_type or product_familly in directly in the 3rd dimension(`X.shape[2]`) of your dataset.

Even if the information is never changing in the timesteps it will be considered in the learning phase, and could be used in prediction. Is it a good idea to do so ? I'm not sure of it.

Now, the comment of Sergey Bushmanov is to consider. Detrending your data in this kind of task is a good step, you could look at algorithm like [STL](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL) to do that for you.

What i would advise you to do if you didn't already, is to have a look at models like [ARMA](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.html?highlight=arma#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA), which can include a [seasonal component](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) in their modelling, and that are tailor made to the case of forecasting univariate time series like yours.

Comment: I will try to implement the solution you suggested. I may update the question or comment here again for further opinions later. Thanks for the thorough explanation and your suggestions, appreciate a lot.